# HTML + CSS - Posição de elemento relativa à div

Tags: html, css

Não estou conseguindo posicionar meu elemento no topo e ao final direito da div. 
Veja que minha div está de cor levemente amarelada, e meu elemento "x" em vermelho. Este "x" é o que quero posicionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
.ExcluirRelativePosition {
position: absolute;
top: -10px;
left: 115px;
```

}

Gostaria de saber como posicionar meu elemento independente do tamanho da Div, pois minha div varia de tamanho, então meu `position: absolute;` precisa trabalhar com algo dinâmico e não por pixels como a maioria dos exemplos disponíveis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você poderia usar `top` e `right` ao invés de `left`. Exemplo:

```
.ExcluirRelativePosition {
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px; /* O botão vai sempre ficar ao final da div */
}
```